# 'UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h' not found with flutter and xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

Started getting this error after upgrading flutter on my mac(Monterey). Failing to render iOS versions for flutter app in xcode. Anyone encountered this before?

Flutter 3.0.5, Xcode Version 13.2.1

Comment: What is the version of Flutter and Xcode?

Comment: Xcode Version 13.2.1, Flutter 3.0.5

Comment: update xcode to 13.4.1

Comment: Thank you so much @HosseinAsadi. This option of updating xcode to 13.4.1 worked perfectly.